# generating a working war file with maven for a spring-boot web application

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

We have a maven-managed spring-boot application that we now need to deploy in tomcat using a WAR file. During development, we used maven to start an embedded tomcat with the command:

```
mvn -D"-classpath %classpath package.path.App" -D"exec.executable=java" process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
```

I can build a war file by running `mvn war:war`, but if I try to deploy the resulting war, an error is produced:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No SpringApplication sources have been defined. Either override the configure method or add an @Configuration annotation
```

I tried adding a `mainClass` directive to the `maven-war-plugin`'s configuration, but to no avail.

Comment: Do you use Eclipse to develop the project? If so, try right click on the project -> Export.

Comment: Have you configured a SpringBootServletInitializer with your @SpringApplication annotated class to boot up your application?

Comment: @dunni I have no @SpringApplication class (I did not even find such an annotation in any spring documentation), I have a class with a `main(args)` function that does `SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class);` and `app.run(args);`. For the maven embedded tomcat, I do have a class extending `SpringBootServletInitializer`, but did not need to declare it anywhere. I will look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to build a war following dunni's advice.

Basically, I needed to add a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on the class extending `SpringBootServletInitializer`, and override its `configure` method.

So the diff of my code is like:

```
+@SpringBootApplication
 public class WebAppInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

+        @Override
+       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
+               return application.sources(App.class);
+       }
```

I still have an error but only after spring starts, but I will ask about that in a different question.