# bean creator function not called when packaging into war in spring application

Tags: java, spring, war

I have a spring REST application, which works fine if ran using mvn exec with embedded tomcat (beans get created fine, @Autowired works as expected, etc.).

If, however, I create a WAR using mvn package and deploy it into an existing tomcat, some bean creator functions do not get called.

For example, I have a bean creator function

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(LocalizedMessages messages) {
    // create and configure ObjectMapper with custom serializer
}
```

Which gets called when with an embedded tomcat, and does not get called when using war. I tried to add the containing class to the SpringApplicationBuilder's sources, but that did not have any effect.

Does anyone have a suggestion how I could get the war version to work properly?

**Some extra details**

I am using spring-boot 1.2 with the spring-boot-starter-web maven dependency, and originally I was using an `App` class with a `main` function to create and start a new SpringApplication (which in turn started an embedded tomcat), and also the `App` class has appropriate `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotations so that all `@Component`s and `@Configuration`s are appropriately handled.

With the war packaging, I created a class that extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` and has a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation that adds the above `App.class` to the SpringApplicationBuilder's source list (see [generating a working war file with maven for a spring-boot web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883749)). I even tried to list *all* `@Component`s among the sources, but the above mentioned bean creator functions are still not called.

Comment: Did you specify `<context:component-scan/>`, *<mvc:annotation-driven/>` or something alike in the war's application context?

Comment: @Alexander I do not use any spring xml configuration at all, I am using spring-boot with spring-boot-starter-web.

Comment: ah ok. please add this information to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, a collegaue of mine found the solution:

It seems that the `App` class had to extend `SpringBootServerInitializer` (not an other class), and define itself among the sources in the SpringApplicationBuilder. After that, `@ComponentScan` began to work magically.

I hope this helps soneone. :)